# Импорт компонента в несколько разных не связанных модулей

Tags: angular2

Имеется приложение. Сделано по принципу lazy loading.
Каждая страница это отдельный модуль. Данные модули не объедены нигде единым каким то модулем. Необходимо подключить один компонент в несколько модулей (таких компонентов будет в итоге несколько)
При попытке это сделать, говорит что компонент не включен в данный модуль(пытался подключить его в главный модуль тоже),

Error: Template parse errors:
    'app-app-card' is not a known element:
    1. If 'app-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

если декларирую в текущий модуль(текущей страницы), он работает, но когда пытаюсь вывести на другой странице и соответственно импортирую там, то получаю ошибку(абсолютно логичную) что компонент подключен в несколько модулей. Как быть?

Попробовал в модуль в котом хочу вывести компонент, добавить

```
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
```

Ошибки пропали но содержимого компонента нет.

Главный модуль

```
/*Modules*/
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AuthorizationModule } from './modules/authorization/authorization.module';
import { ToasterModule, ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { SidebarModule } from 'ng-sidebar';

/*3rd party components*/
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

/*services*/
import { Ng2Webstorage } from 'ng2-webstorage';
import { appRouter } from './app.router';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

/*Import containers*/
import {
    FullLayout,
    SimpleLayout,
    AuthLayout
} from './containers';

const APP_CONTAINERS = [
    FullLayout,
    SimpleLayout,
    AuthLayout
];

/*Import app components*/
import {
    AppAside,
    AppBreadcrumbs,
    AppFooter,
    AppHeader,
    AppSidebar,
    AppSidebarFooter,
    AppSidebarForm,
    AppSidebarHeader
} from './components';

const APP_COMPONENTS = [
    AppAside,
    AppBreadcrumbs,
    AppFooter,
    AppHeader,
    AppSidebar,
    AppSidebarFooter,
    AppSidebarForm,
    AppSidebarHeader
];

/*Import directives*/
import {
    AsideToggleDirective,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES
} from './directives';
import {HttpInterceptorService} from './services/http-interceptor.service';
import {CardService} from './services/card.service';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {TokenService} from './services/token.service';
import {MainRequestService} from './services/main-request.service';
import { AppCardComponent } from './components/app-card/app-card.component';

const APP_DIRECTIVES = [
    AsideToggleDirective,
    NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        appRouter,
        ToasterModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        AuthorizationModule,
        Ng2Webstorage,
        BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
        TooltipModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        SidebarModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...APP_CONTAINERS,
        ...APP_COMPONENTS,
        ...APP_DIRECTIVES,
        AppCardComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpInterceptorService, multi: true},
        CardService,
        TokenService,
        MainRequestService,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Роутинг(собственно там модули и "подключаются")

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthGuard } from './modules/authorization/_services/index';

/*Import Containers*/
import {
    FullLayout,
    AuthLayout
} from './containers';

export const router: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: FullLayout,
        data: {
            title: 'Головна'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/home/home.module#HomeModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'gallery',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/gallery/gallery.module#GalleryModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'about',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/about/about.module#AboutModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/settings/settings.module#SettingsModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'balance-fill',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/balance-fill/balance-fill.module#BalanceFillModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'withdrawal-money',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/withdrawal-money/withdrawal-money.module#WithdrawalMoneyModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'history',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/history/history.module#HistoryModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'set-bill',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/set-bill/set-bill.module#SetBillModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'wallet',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: 'app/pages/wallet/wallet.module#WalletModule',
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const appRouter: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(router);
```

Решил создать шеред модуль. В котором задекларирую компонент и експортирую, далее буду подключать этот модуль в необходимых мне модулях и их компонентах. Но не сработало пока что

Шеред модуль

```
      import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
        import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

        /*components*/
        import {AppCardComponent} from '../../components/app-card/app-card.component';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            CommonModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            AppCardComponent
        ],
        exports: [
            AppCardComponent
        ]
    })
    export class SharedModule {
    }
```

Модуль компонента где хочу использовать

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BalanceFillComponent } from "app/pages/balance-fill/balance-fill.component";

import { balanceFillRouter } from './balance-fill.router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {SharedModule} from '../shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ BalanceFillComponent ],
  imports: [
      balanceFillRouter,
      FormsModule,
      SharedModule
  ]
})

export class BalanceFillModule {}
```

компонент который нужно "розшарить"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-app-card',
      templateUrl: './app-card.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app-card.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppCardComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }
```

и в шаблон `BalanceFillComponent` вставляю селектор компонента `app-app-card`

Comment: Так а где ты этот можуль импортируешь?

Comment: SharedModule в котором нужный мне компонент, я импортирую в другой модуль в котором хочу использовать данный компонент.

имеется компонент_1, он импортирован в шеред модуль, шеред модуль импортирую в модуль_2(где лежит компонент_2), и собственно в компонент_2 я пытаюсь вставить  селектор компонент_1

Comment: не видно этого в приведенном коде

Comment: добавил описание

Comment: я уже пробовал и не просто компонент создавать а модуль с компонентом, в него импортировать и экспортировать компонент. далее этот модуль-компонент, импортирую в нужный мне другой модуль2 и в текущем компоненте модуля2 вывожу комонент1. но не получилось.

Comment: в общем. как правильно вывести компонент одного модуля в компоненте других модулей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы иметь возможность подключать компонент в разные модули, необходимо (как один из вариантов) - создать общий модуль (`SharedModule`)

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {TestCoComponent} from '../../components/test-co/test-co.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        TestCoComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        TestCoComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

и в нем подключать все нужные вам компоненты, далее `SharedModule` импортировать в другие модуль которые являются родителем компоненты в котором нам необходимо вывести инфу.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from "app/pages/home/home.component";

import { homeRouter } from './home.router';
import {SharedModule} from '../../modules/shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
  imports: [ homeRouter, SharedModule ]
})

export class HomeModule {}
```

Компонент модуля `HomeModule`

```
<div>
    <app-test-co></app-test-co> `<--- вывод инфы "розшареного` компонента"
  <div>Home Component MAIN PAGE</div>
  <div>Open the chrome dev tool and go to Network tab.
    Navigate to other page to see lazy load module works. You will see it load the *.chunk.js file when you visit that page for forst time.</div>
</div>
```

---

Не знаю почему с первого раза не сработал, хотя пробовал так же. "Утро вечера мудренее" сделал за пару минут.
Спасибо [источнику](https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-4-shared-modules-18ac50f24852) где все доступно описано и так же как сервис розшарить.